# Snapshot listener, get the document name, Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I am adding a snapshot listener to a firebase Collection/Document/Collection to get the data as it is updated

The issue I am having is I run through a for loop and as it gets the i in the for loop I then use that string (collection name), to direct the snapshot listener, when the data comes in it will add to the data already there rather than change the data. because it doesn't touch the code to get the collection name, as far as I know.

What I need to do is to be able to add the data to a dictionary that has [String:Any], so I can have the ["collection name":name, "document name": document id, "info":document data], this is fine on first run but when data is changed it only get the data from the changed listener but I don't know how I can get it to get the collection name so I can remove that document from the dictionary before adding the new data.

```
func getClockOutData(completion: @escaping (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    for i in projectsList {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("Projects").document(i).collection("TimeSheets").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Tony the error was \(err.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Tony dataC A get is \(i)")
                if let projDocs = snapshot?.documents {
                    print("Tony dataC get is \(i)")
                    for d in projDocs {
                        let dataG = d.data()
                        let dateG = d.documentID
                        let dataCT = ["project":i, "dateG":dateG, "inf":dataG] as [String : Any]
                        print("Tony dataC is \(dataCT)")
                        self.dataC.append(dataCT)
                    }
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the project name (i) when the snapshot fires again with the changes?

I want that so I can create a for loop to check the project and add all the data from the project to a dict with all the same project name grouped and then run through that loop when there are changes to remove the project info before it is re appended

Answer (score 0):

When you're retrieving the documents from the subcollection, no data from the parent document is retrieved.

So you will either have to load the parent document to get that information, or get the information from the context where you make this request (as likely you've loaded the parent document before as part of determining `projectsList`).